Where do I find documentation on different biblatex macros?
I'm trying to make some changes to the default formatting of various bibliography entries, which involves using \renewbibmacro, but sometimes it's not clear which bibmacro I need to work with.
For example, I want to change the volume and number format from "1.2" to "1(2)". At first I tried \renewbibmacro{volume+number}{\printfield[bold]{volume}\printfield[parens]{number}} but got the error Macro 'volume+number' undefined. Apparently I need to use the volume+number+eid macro, even though I'm not using the eid field.
I downloaded the package documentation here but I can't find the information I need

if you are a Windows user, then run the command texdoc biblatex, the corresponding documentation will opens in a new window

I use overleaf.

Documentation for biblatex available at https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex?lang=en and https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/

Thanks, yes I already downloaded the documentation but there's nothing in there about the bibmacros I need

The bibmacros are not documented as which are provided depends on the style you use: you'll need to open the relevant sources and read them over

Its better to refer the documentation from page numbers 166 onwards

Thanks @JosephWright. I'm using ext-numeric-comp style. Do you know where I can start looking for the sources?

Thanks to some initial guidance from @joseph-wright in the comments, I've found what I need...
The source code for biblatex is here. The tex/latex/biblatex/bbx directory contains .bbx files with code for each biblatex style - looking in the numeric-comp.bbx file sent me first to the numeric.bbx and then to the standard.bbx file. Here I found the source code for each different type of bibliography entry - looking at the article code I can see that the journal+issuetitle macro is used, which in turn uses the volume+number+eid macro.

If you use biblatex-ext styles, you may also want to have a quick look at the corresponding styles in tex/latex/biblatex-ext/, ext-standard.bbx is definitely worth a look. (If you instead take the standard biblatex definitions you will probably still get what you want in most cases, but you might disable biblatex-ext features if you overwrite its macros with modified standard definitions instead of modified biblatex-ext definitions).

Thanks I'll take a look
